# Javascript test if object has any keys that are not undefined or null

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object that is evaluating as undefined when I try to read its keys using Object.keys().  However, when I do Object.keys().length I get 1.

How can I test an object for presence if any key other than undefined or null.

I've tried the following, but still get errors. I'm essentially just checking the first element to see if it is null or undefined.  I'm guessing there may be a better way to run this kind of check.

I've googled and seen cases of handling a search for a specific property, but that is not how my object is setup.  I actually have an object with nested objects. `Player1` and `Player2` can be any value.

```
var data =
    { 
      player1:
       { team: team1,
         score: 6 },
      player2:
       { team: team2,
         score: 4} 
    }
```

Here is what my object can also look like and it is causing `undefined` to be displayed when I attempt to loop through and display it in a table.

```
{ undefined:
   { team: undefined,
     score: '0'} }
```

As you can see doing a length check will return 1.  So I'm guessing I have to check for the first elemnent `data[0]`?  That check works, but is that the best way to handle this?

```
if (Object.keys(data[0]) === null){
do something
}
```

Comment: data[0] is undefined. What are you trying to do?

Comment: *"Javascript test if object has any keys that are not undefined or null"* The *keys* (property names) in an object will **never** be `undefined` or `null`. Property names are always strings or Symbols. The question is really unclear, please do reply to @mehulmpt's question above.

Comment: I've added more detail to the question.  `data[0]` is indeed undefined.  Is checking for `data[0]` the only way to find out if `data` does not contain any elements?  My assumption was that I could do `if (Object.keys(data[0]) === null){
do something
}`

Comment: I selected Arash's answer because it addressed my question. Getting the length on my object as shown in my question was giving me a value of 1.  The test that worked for me was doing a test on  `data` itself.  I did not think to do that because my assumption was that if I am getting a value greater than 0 on the object length, then doing a test on the object itself would not give false.

Comment: @mo_maat: *"`data[0]` is indeed undefined"* Right, but that's not the property *key*. That's the property *value* (or rather, the value you get when the object doesn't have a property by the name you requested). The property *key* you're checking there is `"0"`. Since `data` doesn't have a property called `"0"`, you get `undefined`. Again: Keys cannot be `undefined`, `null`, or indeed anything but a string or Symbol.

Comment: Makes sense!  I understand now.  I was too fixated on looping through keys and forgot about the values. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (Object.keys(data).length === 0){
    // There are no keys
}
```

Also check that `data` itself isn't `null` or `undefined`.

```
if (!data || typeof data !== "object" || Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
    // This is either a null, undefined, not an object, or an object with no keys
}
```

Comment: Won't work for `{one: undefined, two: undefined}`

Answer (score 4):

> I have an object that is evaluating as undefined

because `data[0]` is **undefined**

Directly use

```
if ( Object.keys( data ).length == 0 )
{
   do something
}
```

Comment: data[0] is undefined, not null

Comment: @mehulmpt You are right about that, I have fixed the same.